# Android cpp sources are being included in jar file

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk

I am porting my game to Android. The game is written in C++ and I am using NDK to run the game logic code.

I put the Android specific Java sources together with my C++ sources (actualy it is a subfolder src/platform/android which contains C++ and Java source files). The problem is, since the source dir is the same for C++ and Java, when I build my jar file ant includes all my .cpp files into the jar.

How can I make ant ignore .cpp and .mm (iPhone version) files?

Comment: Why keep CPP files in the Java tree?

Comment: Particularly since the NDK docs indicate they are supposed to go in a `jni/` directory off the project root, IIRC.

Comment: @AlexCohn Actually the Java sources are on the C++ tree. I have a folder named src and it makes sense to keep all sources there. Its not like they are not organized in subfolders.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't just follow what the documentation indicate because it is a multiplatform project. Keeping C++ sources in a jni directory would make no sense for the iOS/PC builds.

Comment: I would suggest to put all Java into **src/java** directory, and set this as the root path for your Java build. This subtree will contain no C or C++ files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom ant script you can use something like this:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<jar jarfile="${dir.dist}/xxx.jar" 
     basedir="${dir.build}"
     excludes="**/*.cpp"/>
</target>
```

Comment: I am not using a custom ant script. I am using the default Android SDK build.xml. I'll take a look at the default build.xml and see if I can add the exclude, but it would be good to have a solution that can be done in the project and not changing the SDK.